# REGEXP_LIKE, oracle, sql, query, understanding

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Please help me understand the below query. I am new to REGEXP_LIKE in oracle sql. I know ^A-Z means starts with A-Z or a-z, is that correct? I don't understand the rest like the -\''. I have no idea what that is doing exactly. I would appreciate some help to help me understand what this is doing. Thanks for your help.

My Attempt at understanding:
[^a-zA-Z] means any character that IS NOT a-z OR A-Z

```
   SELECT d,name_type,effdt,name, name1, name2, name3
    FROM table1
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name3, '[^A-Za-z, -\'']')
    or REGEXP_LIKE(name1, '[^A-Za-z, -\'']')
    or REGEXP_LIKE(name2, '[^A-Za-z, -\'']')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the regexp syntax is not a valid oracle* regexp syntax, but I think i can deduce what it was supposed to mean.

Within brackets, minus sign denotes range of characters, therefore in your current query it is pretty unclear what range you're trying to specify.
Also, in seems that in Oracle's dialect minus sign needs to be either last or first character in brackets (I did not know it before answering this question to be honest).

^ Means start of the string if it is the first character in regexp, but it means "all characters except of:" when it's inside square brackets.

Square brackets specify sets of characters that are allowed, or, when preceded with ^, that are not allowed.

After fixing the syntactical error mentioned above, we get the following regexp:

```
with ex as (
   select 'AAA' x from dual union all
   select 'AA''A' x from dual union all
   select 'AA A' x from dual union all
   select 'AA''A' x from dual union all
   select 'AA A' from dual union all
   select 'A1AA' from dual union all
   select 'AA\A' from dual union all
   select 'A-AA' from dual union all
   select '123fojq3t' from dual
)
select ex.x
  from ex 
 where REGEXP_LIKE(ex.x, '[^A-Za-z \''-]')
```

So to understand the brackets:

```
[^
A-Za-z   any character between a-z or A-Z  
,        comma 
         (space)
\        backslash. Backslash is not treated as escape character here, as single quote does not need escaping
''       single quote. We use double quote, so that the Oracle does not think that this is the end of the regexp
-        hyphen. It apparently is important that it is the last character here
]
```

So, this is some set of charaters. Now, because there is '^', regexp like will mean:
Find me a first character that is NOT in the set above.

It is easier to understand this when you use regexp_instr instead of regexp_like:

```
with ex as (
   select 'AAA' x from dual union all
   select 'AA''A' x from dual union all
   select 'AA A' x from dual union all
   select 'AA''A' x from dual union all
   select 'AA A' from dual union all
   select 'A1AA' from dual union all
   select 'AA\A' from dual union all
   select 'A-AA' from dual union all
   select '123fojq3t' from dual
)
select ex.x,
       REGEXP_instr(ex.x, '[^A-Za-z \''-]')
  from ex
```

- - I am using 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess -

```
[] - Brackets are used to define a class. Anything inside brackets will be matched with the column values of name1, name2 and name3
^ - Starting of the characters but negation when inside brackets.
A-Z or a-z or , or space or - or \ or " - Starting characters of the columns name1, name2, name3
```